Adding backgroundTask to WindowGroup breaks AccentColor
I am working on a rather simple iOS app. I set AccentColor in assets to green, and every button in my app become green. As soon as I add .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("some identifier")) to WindowGroup inside my App, suddenly all buttons become blue.
Here is the code:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            /* list of models */
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
        .onChange(of: scenePhase, initial: true) { newPhase, _ in
            if newPhase == .active {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
            } else if newPhase == .background {
                scheduleAppRefresh()
            }
        }
        // Adding this .backgroundTask brakes AccentColor. Color on all buttons is blue
        // instead of AccentColor (which should be green).
        // If I remove whole .backgroundTask, AccentColor works.
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("com.mydomain.someapp.rescheduleNotifications")) {
            await rescheduleNotifications()
        }
    }
    func rescheduleNotifications() async {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        NotificationManager.CreateNotifications(modelContainer: sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

This only happens on a real iPhone. It works perfectly fine on a Simulator. Any idea?

If it is working on a simulator but doesn't work on a real phone, try checking the accessibility settings on the iPhone, including per-app settings. Having said that, I can't think what setting might cause this behavior.

I checked accessibility settings, and nothing is turned on. It's also strange for me. If I add .tint(.green) to ContentView(), it also works, but it's more of a workaround than solution.

This is seems to be an iOS 18 bug caused by using backgroundTask  in together with @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase.
If you remove either, you should see that you get your accent color back.
You can either keep your .tint() fix, or move the .onChange(of: scenePhase, initial: true) inside your ContentView, but beware that this can be problematic because of the way it works:

If you read the phase from within an App instance, you obtain an aggregate value that reflects the phases of all the scenes in your app. The app reports a value of ScenePhase.active if any scene is active, or a value of ScenePhase.inactive when no scenes are active. This includes multiple scene instances created from a single scene declaration; for example, from a WindowGroup. When an app enters the ScenePhase.background phase, expect the app to terminate soon after.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase
